# Getting text from window (notepad)

Tags: python-3.x, winapi

I've started learning python few days ago and stuck while I was trying to get text from notepad

the code below  returning me Window title but when I'm using win32gui.GetWindowText(control) it returns null. Could someone mark my mistake here? Thank you in advance

```
import time
import win32gui

while True:
    window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    title = win32gui.GetWindowText(window)
    control = win32gui.FindWindowEx(window, 0, 'Edit', None)
    print('text: ', win32gui.GetWindowText(window))
    print('control to %s, window to %s' %(str(control),  str(window)))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You didn't check for errors. What debugging have you done? Anyway you are not interested in Notepad. What is the real target? Are you sure that this approach is correct for the real target.

Comment: *"Could someone mark my mistake here?"* - You are hacking against low-level implementation details, instead of using the infrastructure meant to be used here: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan
I've done debugging and It worked as It should but I was wrong and forgot about funcationality of GetWindowText

Comment: Apparently it not work as it should. I'm not sure you fully appreciate what I mean by any of the points made in my comment.

Answer (score 3):

MSDN tells you twice in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx) that this will not work!

> GetWindowText cannot retrieve the text of a control in another application
>
> To retrieve the text of a control in another process, send a WM_GETTEXT message directly instead of calling GetWindowText.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I completly forgot about it and I have been using it in the past with C#

length = win32gui.SendMessage(control, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, 255, buf)
result = buf[:length]

As I saw it should work like this but I'm not getting any string value from notepad (length of the typed word is working properly)